# Generate Thumbnail of Pdf in Android

Tags: android, image, pdf, pdfbox

I want to generate the image(thumbnail) from pdf file just like done by **WhatsApp** as shown below
[image: WhatsApp]

I have tried

1. **PDFBox** (https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android)
2. **Tika** (compile 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.11')
3. **AndroidPdfViewer** (https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

and still unable to find a way to generate image from pdf.

---

***PDFBox:***

There is a github issue that deals with this problem (https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/3) but this is still unresolved.

**Note:** I am successfully able to extract image from PDF using **PDFBOX**

---

***AndroidPdfViewer:***

Github issue (https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/49)

Comment: Whatsapp does it server-side.

Comment: Hello @shanraisshan. I'm trying to achieve a similar functionality. Could you please share some sample code, how you achieve it? Or some link which could guide me for the same. Best Regards

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [**PdfiumAndroid**](https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid) as mentioned by [**barteksc**](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/49) here.

**Still working in 2021...**

Sample Code for generating **Pdf thumb**

```
//PdfiumAndroid (https://github.com/barteksc/PdfiumAndroid)
//https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/49
void generateImageFromPdf(Uri pdfUri) {
    int pageNumber = 0;
    PdfiumCore pdfiumCore = new PdfiumCore(this);
    try {
        //http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
        ParcelFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(pdfUri, "r");
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fd);
        pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        int width = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        int height = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(pdfDocument, bmp, pageNumber, 0, 0, width, height);
        saveImage(bmp);
        pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument); // important!
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //todo with exception
    }
}

public final static String FOLDER = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PDF";
private void saveImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        File folder = new File(FOLDER);
        if(!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(folder, "PDF.png");
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //todo with exception
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //todo with exception
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:**

Include the library in the build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

**For generating Image of any PDF Page:**

Call the method **generateImageFromPdf(uri)** by passing any *PDF uri* that is stored in your storage.

The method will generate the **PDF.png** in the PDF folder of your storage.

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: How can I get the "ParcelFileDescriptor fd" from Assets?

Comment: Hi, I not get error but the png is not create to my storage. and I think the code `ParcelFileDescriptor fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(pdfUri, "r");` is not working

Comment: not working, should i save the bitmap, cannot i just set imageview with the generated bitmap?

Comment: Not Working. When i set the bitmap to imageView it does not show anything.

Comment: This library increases my app size by 15MB. Is there any alternative available for just creating the thumbnail.

Comment: @NileshRathore have you found out any solution? If yes, can you please share I am also with the same.

Answer (score 8):

Using Android PDFRenderer Component

```kotlin
with(context) {
    contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")?.use { parcelFileDescriptor ->
        val pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor).openPage(0)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pdfRenderer.width, pdfRenderer.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        pdfRenderer.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
        pdfRenderer.close()      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val file = Constant.allMediaList[position]
val filename = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(file)
if (file != null) {
    if (file.endsWith(".pdf")){
        val fd :ParcelFileDescriptor= ParcelFileDescriptor.open(filename,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE)
        val pageNum: Int  = 0;
        val pdfiumCore: PdfiumCore  = PdfiumCore(mContext);
        try {
            val pdfDocument: PdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fd);
            pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, pageNum);
            val width:  Int  = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, pageNum);
            val height:  Int = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, pageNum);

            // ARGB_8888 - best quality, high memory usage, higher possibility of OutOfMemoryError
            // RGB_565 - little worse quality, twice less memory usage
            val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(pdfDocument, bitmap, pageNum, 0, 0,width, height);
            //if you need to render annotations and form fields, you can use
            //the same method above adding 'true' as last param

            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(bitmap).into(holder.thumbnail)

            pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument); // important!
        } catch(ex: IOException) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap myBitmap = generateImageFromPdf(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", Pdf_File.get(position).getAbsoluteFile()));
    holder.iv_icon.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}

Bitmap generateImageFromPdf(Uri pdfUri) {
    int pageNumber = 0;
    PdfiumCore pdfiumCore = new PdfiumCore(context);
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    try {
        //http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
        ParcelFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(pdfUri, "r");
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = pdfiumCore.newDocument(fd);
        pdfiumCore.openPage(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        int width = pdfiumCore.getPageWidthPoint(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        int height = pdfiumCore.getPageHeightPoint(pdfDocument, pageNumber);
        Log.e("Width_height", "" + width + " " + height);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        pdfiumCore.renderPageBitmap(pdfDocument, bmp, pageNumber, 0, 0, width, height);
        pdfiumCore.closeDocument(pdfDocument);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //todo with exception
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. In Java.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uriFile, "r");
try (PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
     PdfRenderer.Page page = pdfRenderer.openPage(0)) {

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(thumbnailPath.toFile())) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error creating thumbnail", e);

}
```