# How to show pdf in image view android?

Tags: java, android, pdf

This below code is pick image from device. how to pick pdf from device.and how to show a pdf in Image view?

```
  bt_gall .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Comment: `ImageView` doesn't support printing pdf

Comment: `pdf` files are **not images**.

Answer (score 0):

To select pdf Try This

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), 1);
```

To Set Pdf as image you need to create thumbnail of pdf

To create Thumbnail Check This,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829523/3416642

Hope this will help you.

Comment: in example, when i press the button i want to choose both image file or pdf file.what is the code?

Comment: @spodee pass multple MIME type - Check This http://stackoverflow.com/a/33117677/3416642

Comment: when i try this code    [Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Document"), 1);]     only image wass selected.