# How to create a thumbnail of the first page of the file in android application? The file can be pdf, word, excel

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, document

I would like to create thumbnail of attached file first page. The file can be pdf word, excel...

Like WhatsApp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6rCy.jpg

MyCode is:

```
    private fun selectDocument() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
        type = "*/*"
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    }
    activity?.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), REQUEST_DOCUMENT_GET)
}

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    cameraHelper?.onActivityResultNoCrop(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DOCUMENT_GET && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val path = data?.data?.path

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828396/generate-thumbnail-of-pdf-in-android

Comment: Android has nothing built in for this, sorry.